# Custom logo on top of UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I've read plenty of requests about a full-on custom `UINavigationBar` background, but what I want is to overlay a logo on the default `UINavigationBar` instead of text. Preferably, I'd like to apply it to a subclass of `UINavigationBar` called CustomNavigationBar.

Answer (score 28):

Neat tricks, Shadow.

If you just want to add a logo instead of a title, that's easy. Set the titleView on your navigationItem, like so:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

Comment: Oh clever, that is pretty nice. Much easier than what I had :)

Comment: +2!!!!!!! An elegant solution, with **correct memory management!!!!!!!!!!!!**. My, I wish memory management could be easier....

Comment: this conflicts with push navigation at least with ios9

Answer (score 1):

This page has some code you can look at as he explains how to do some custom things to the nav controller.
http://web.archive.org/web/20161220074043/http://foobarpig.com/iphone/uinavigationbar-with-solid-color-or-image-background.html

Here is another reference as well.
http://web.archive.org/web/20120815192006/http://www.developers-life.com/custom-uinavigationbar-with-image-and-back-button.html

Comment: Both of those are exactly what I said was unneeded - a full custom UINavigationBar background. I just need to somehow override the text drawn on the UINavigationBar with an image. Thanks for the suggestion though.